# What happens if we call an emit event on a socket that has already disconnected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

What will happen if I run the following code if the socket has already disconnected?

```
socket.emit("event", event_data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Jim Ciaston's answer is correct.

But, to be sure, there's an easy way to check!

Just run

```
socket.emit("event", {event: 'data', count: 1})
socket.disconnect()
socket.emit("event", {event: 'data': count: 2})
```

on the server, and on the client side print the event data and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

If the socket is disconnected, no information will be passed I'm assuming. Almost like if you try to start the car without the keys.